# How we import access database(.mdb) into sql server 2008 in C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server-2008, ms-access

I used access database in my project. I want to import full data of my database to sql server 2008. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Later versions of Access have an Upsizing Wizerd built-in which will assist you in migrating your Access DB to SQL Server.  It's usually under the [Database Tools] menu.

Answer (score 2):

you can use SQL Server Import and Export Wizard, check below link for more information

[Importing and Exporting Data by Using the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using the [Upsizing Wizard](http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/how-to/convert-access-database-to-sql-server): open Access database, select Tools menu, and then Database Utilities menu. Upsizing utility is not included in default installation of Microsoft Access, so you’ll need to install in order to benefit of it.

What you export is your data, indexes, and defaults. The great thing is that Upgrading Wizard maintains your table relationships and referential integrity after upsizing. Be aware, upsizing operation means only a conversion for you i.e. it won’t take advantage of SQL Server features.

You’ll have some fun converting Access queries to SQL Server views or stored procedures as wizard didn’t make it.